# Why do the features of pcl_ros decrease

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

Now we have a mind to rearrange our pcl ros wrappers, jsk_pcl_ros(http: //sourceforge.net/p/jsk-ros-pkg/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/jsk_pcl_ros/),
and to send our features to the upstream,https:// github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/fuerte-devel/pcl_ros.

But when I see the code of pcl_ros, I feel that the features of the codes are decreasing as the branches of pcl_ros are updated.
For example, perception_pcl/pcl_ros/src/{segmentation,surface} are lost.
We are also lost about that.

If we send a pull request to bring back the lost features, does ros-perception accept it?
And if we send our features to them, does they accept it?
What is the policy of maintenance of pcl_ros?

Sorry for my strange English.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62128/why-do-the-features-of-pcl_ros-decrease/) by [s-fujii](https://answers.ros.org/users/3822/s-fujii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't speak for the pcl_ros maintainers, but I expect they would accept a well-implemented push request to reinstate missing features.

To make it easy to merge your changes:

- [open an issue](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues) explaining what is being added
- fork the [ros-perception/perception_pcl](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl) repository on github
- make your changes
- test them
- submit a pull request, referring to the relevant issue number

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [s-fujii](https://answers.ros.org/users/3822/s-fujii/) on 2013-05-06**:
I appreciate your detailed answer.

But I want to know whether ros-perception really have a will to merge our pull request if it is good.

I want to avoid needless bother.

Thanks.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-06**:
Go ahead and open the issue. Explain that you will provide a fix if they are willing to review it and merge if appropriate. You can provide a link to this question.